# Setting up `gemstash` to work with `rake release` in Ruby gem

Tags: rubygems, rake

I am trying to set up gemstash such that (1) it operates as a cache for rubygems.org and (2) it serves private gems that I want to test without making them public (yet).

For gems that I want to release to the public, I just have to run rake release in my source repository and the gem is uploaded to rubygems. For private gems, I want to be able to do the the same thing except that they are only uploaded to gemstash.

In my private gem's gemspec file, I have this setting:

spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "http://localhost:9292/private"

And it looks like that almost does the trick, except that when I run rake release, I get prompted to set up an account on gemstash:

> Enter your http://localhost:9292/private credentials.
> Don't have an account yet? Create one at http://localhost:9292/private/sign_up
> Email:

Is there a setting I should have in the gemspec to set my gemstash key, or am I missing something else?